# How to change checked color of disabled check box

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am having labels and checkboxes in table. but when the screen is read-only, the checkbox and other input elements become disabled and the check box check visibility decreased.
I need to make the checkmark look more visible either by changing the color of the check mark or increasing the brightness of the check border.

HTML:

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th colspan="3" style="width: 1800px;">
      <asp:Literal ID="litLabel" runat="server" Text="Service Team" />
    </th>
  </tr>

  <tr id="trSignature" runat="server">
    <td class="boldfont ">
      &nbsp;&nbsp;
      <asp:Label ID="lblSignature" runat="server" Text="61" />
    </td>
    <td class="boldfont">
      &nbsp;<input ID="tlblSignature" runat="server" LabelForControl="lblSignature" Text="Certification of Service Coordinator Signature" IsRequiredField="false" />
    </td>
    <td class="ControlLayoutWidth">
      &nbsp;<input type="checkbox" ID="chkSignature" runat="server" IsRequiredField="false" FriendlyFieldName="Signature" AutoPostBack="true">
      </>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

this is how it looked on the UI, which is hard to see the checkbox
[image]

I tried to do it with the same CSS from this page http://jsfiddle.net/5g3w32ug/, but the check box is not visible at all.
Please let me know how can we achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

> Give high priority to the checkbox: checked styles...

```css
input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label::after {
   content: '';
   position: absolute;
   width: 1.2ex;
   height: 0.4ex;
   background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
   top: 0.9ex;
   left: 0.4ex;
   border: 3px solid blue;
   border-top: none;
   border-right: none;
   -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
   -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
   -o-transform: rotate(-45deg);
   -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg);
   transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label::before{
    
     background-color:#FFA500;
}

input[type="checkbox"] {
   line-height: 2.1ex;
}

input[type="radio"],
input[type="checkbox"] {
    position: absolute;
    left: -999em;
}

input[type="checkbox"] + label {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    cursor: pointer;
}

input[type="checkbox"] + label::before {
   content: "";
   display: inline-block;
   vertical-align: -25%;
   height: 2ex;
   width: 2ex;
   background-color: white;
   border: 1px solid rgb(166, 166, 166);
   border-radius: 4px;
   box-shadow: inset 0 2px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.25);
   margin-right: 0.5em;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" name="genres" value="adventure" id="adventure_id">
<label for="adventure_id" style="font-family: 'SExtralight'; font-size:14px;">Adventure</label>
```

Comment: I am having scenario for label first and checkbox second as shown in question. I tried your solution and checkbox is not visible at all. Please correct if I am doing some thing wrong

Comment: Provide your code, not sample code it will be helpful.

Comment: I already gave my html in the question and applying css with <style> tag in aspx page